# Oracle10g Quote Operator q not working well for & and &&

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Oracle10g supports the quote operator `q`. Using this, it's possible to eliminate previous additional quotation strings in character string literals by choosing
a custom quotation mark delimiter. However, for `&` and `&&`, this doesn't seem to work well. What should I do if I want to input `&` and `&&`?

```
SQL> desc t
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 VARCHAR2(1000)

SQL> insert into t values(q'['test'''',;,,']');           

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values(q'['test''&,,,;;;''']');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values(q'['test''&jj,,,,,'''']');  
Enter value for jj:
```

Comment: What do you mean *doesn't seem to work well* ? what do you get ? are you sure it's not just a `set define off` problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
set define off
```

before running your statements in order to disable the evaluation of SQL*Plus variables.

For details see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2698854

Comment: Not only provide information, also provides a way to get information. 
 Great!

Answer (score 0):

your question is Oracle client specific. For sql+ : did you - SET SCAN OFF?
also - you could SET ESCAPE '\' and then *insert into t values(q'['test \&jj,,,,,'''']');*